# If I leave my (successful) career to start a business, could I get back on the ladder if the business fails?

Tags: career-development

I am currently excelling in my career - especially when compared to other professionals my age. I am about 1 promotion away from being a Global Director of Marketing....it is in sight and totally possible in the next year.

I, however, have a few business ideas and I really think they have leverage and could become successful.

If I leave my career and set up these businesses, could I re-enter my career where I left if the business failed?

Thanks!

Comment: Would working part time be an option?

Answer (score 3):

> could I re-enter my career where I left if the business failed?

It can be difficult to reenter the workforce at the same level if you had a failed business for many reasons. Even reentering after selling a successful business can be hard.

Employers tend to look askance at entrepreneurs and they're not usually the preferred sort of employee. And negotiating from a failed business scenario is a weak negotiating position to be in. I don't know a single entrepreneur who has managed this.

In your case you know marketing is a very competitive profession, and a lot of it is networking, if you're out of the picture for a while it may be even harder to break back in then for a technical person.

If you start your own business, always have an exit strategy.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** There's absolutely no way to tell.

There is no way to tell what impact your going out on your own will have on the relationship with your current professional contacts, nor if you would be able to return to your previous role if it all goes wrong. They may look at your entrepreneurial venture as a positive or negative, especially if it does not end well.

All I would say is that you should probably expect that you will not be able to pick up where you left off in the face of a failed business.  That is not to say you can't, but you need to understand the gravitas of what you are setting out to do in the context of your future career path, and that it *may* be a starting point you can return to, but just as possibly it may not.

As the old saying goes, hope for the best but plan for the worst :)